# XAMPP apache not handling multiple requests

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, xampp

I currently use XAMPP to dev locally on my Windows machine.  I am trying to use multiple ajax calls in my javascript to get the status of an import I'm running.  I believe I have the ajax, jquery, and php all working together correctly, but the ajax calls don't seem to process at the same time.  This doesn't work for my scenario since I launch an import with one of the ajax calls (and I want to check the status throughout).  I can also replicate the issue if I open a page that takes a little longer to load, and then try to load another page at the same time.  The second page won't load until the first is finished loading.  In my apache httpd.conf I have

```
ThreadsPerChild 250
MaxRequestsPerChild  4
```

So my question is, does XAMPP not handle multiple simultaneous requests?  If so, what can I do to enable that or find out what my current issue is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430883/simultaneous-requests-to-php-script/1430890#1430890 (hint: it's probably the sessions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is exactly what Mahn predicted.  Session file locking.  What an evil little trick.  Starting and stopping the session every time I want to write to the session works though.